# How to call javascript method in react-native on Android platform?

Tags: android, react-native

When I click a button in native UI (probably from a fragment container) , I wanna invoke a method from JavaScript, let's call it just like 'jsMethod' or other else. However, I have never handled this situation before.

I am looking up some relative codes from Facebook's document on website and can not find out the key to the problem so far. Anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Check out [Sending Events to JavaScript](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#sending-events-to-javascript) & [Events](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html#events)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To call a JavaScript method from Java, do something like this:

```
ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager = reactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager();
ReactContext reactContext = reactInstanceManager.getCurrentReactContext();

CatalystInstance catalystInstance = reactContext.getCatalystInstance();
WritableNativeArray params = new WritableNativeArray();
params.pushString("Message to show using nameOfJsMethod");
catalystInstance.callFunction("JavaScriptVisibleToJava", "nameOfJsMethod", params);
```

The JavaScript method you want to call must be defined and made visible to Java:

```
import BatchedBridge from "react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/BatchedBridge";

export class ExposedToJava {
  nameOfJsMethod(message) {
    alert(message);
  }
}

const exposedToJava = new ExposedToJava();
BatchedBridge.registerCallableModule("JavaScriptVisibleToJava", exposedToJava);
```

[This sample on Github](https://github.com/petterh/react-native-android-activity) includes a working demo.

**EDIT** I'm told this approach is not officially documented. If your scenario allows, consider taking the advice of @ufxmeng (in the comment to the OP) instead.

Comment: Would there be a way to call it from a WidgetProvider?

Comment: I have no experience with app widgets. My first guess would be no, given limitations in supported widgets -- but I could be wrong.

Comment: how can we get a result from javascript method returning some data?

Comment: NativeModules.className.nativeMethodName("sending something");

Comment: Working with Android 8.0 + react-native 0.62